# displaying public virtual property in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have the following model:

```
public class ActiveProducts
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

and for data context I have:

```
public DbSet<ActiveProduct> ActiveProducts { get; set; }
```

I wanted to create a controller and views to do the CRUD operations

How would I be able to generate a view for the create and edit so that I have a drop down list of products?

I used the standard method of creating a controller using the model, with the CRUD operations and it didn't render out anything for the create.

Comment: so in your database tables.. `ActiveProducts` has a property that holds the *primary key* of the `Product` table? It doesn't look like it based on the model you provided

Comment: Yeah there is there is an ID field and a Product_ID field

Comment: did my solution help you with your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since `Product_ID` holds the *primary key* value of the `Products` table, then this should work in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Product_ID = new SelectList(db.Product, "ID", "Product");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID, Product_ID" /*etc*/)] ActiveProducts activeProducts)
{
    ViewBag.Product_ID = new SelectList(db.Product, "ID", "Product", activeProducts.Product_ID);
}
```

then in your Create View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product_ID, "Product:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Product_ID", null, "-- Select Product --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```